# Substitute placeholder function in integral using sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I am using `sympy` to evaluate a rather complex eigenvalue problem that relies on several state functions. I would like to be able to use placeholder functions that I can generate the integral and evaluate the dependence of the integral on the input function later.

```
import sympy as s
x, L = s.symbols('x L')
Q = s.Function('Q')(x)

# do some sort of integration
e = s.integrate(Q, (x, -L, L))
print(e)
# Integral(Q(x), (x, -L, L))

# evaluate a simple linear function
print(e.subs(Q, x))
# Integral(Q(x), (x, -L, L))
# Expected: Integral(x, (x, -L, L))
#       Or: 0 (evaluation)

# intermediate work around
interm = Q
e = s.integrate(interm.subs(Q, x), (x, -L, L))
print(e)
# 0 (expected)
```

As you can see, the evaluation of the integral does not allow for function substitution. Of course, I can perform the substitution at any point before the `x` integration of `Q`, but it would be convenient to perform substitution later. Is there a way around this? Or, is there a reason why this is avoided by `sympy` by design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior of `subs` on `Integral` has been changed in the development version of SymPy (see https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/release-notes-for-0.7.4#unification-of-sum-product-and-integral-classes). We plan to do a release within the next few weeks. Your example works in the development version:

```
>>> # This is in the development version
>>> print(e.subs(Q, x))
Integral(x, (x, -L, L))
```

As a workaround, you can use `replace` instead of `subs`:

```
>>> # This is in 0.7.3
>>> print(e.replace(Q, x))
Integral(x, (x, -L, L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, will replace continue to work when the new version is released? Also, is there a reason for using either subs or replace?

Comment: Yes replace will continue to work. replace is generally used for much more advanced replacement. See it's documentation. subs is good for evaluation because it takes mathematics into account, especially with integrals and derivatives.